# Placeholders with spring Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

I want to use placeholders with spring value annotation, I wasn't able to find some example.Somebody can point me a link with example.
e.g.

properties file

```
service.scheduled=You have successfully scheduled service {0}.
```

Java Spring code:

```
@Value("${service.scheduled}")
private String scheduleNotification
```

I want dynamic placeholder substitution in properties placeholder "{0}" .I don't have problem with reading property file. I don't know , is this possible with this spring value annotation injection implementation.

Comment: What problem exactly do you have?
Have you added <context:property-placeholder location='database.properties'/> to your config?

Comment: what would you like to substitute there? however I am not sure if something like that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your properties file in the `root-context.xml` (or whatever your Spring configuration is called).

#### Defining a Spring Bean for the properties

This defines a bean, from which you can read out the property values using the `@Value` annotation (you don't have to refer to the name of the bean, you can use the property normally):

```
<bean id="DBProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

#### Using Spring Context

Also, the following should work too if you are using Spring Context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
```

This is one is definitely simpler, however AFAIK in this case you cannot use the property values in the Spring configuration files (FIXME).